# Replace load balancer behind a privatelink to migrate users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nlb, aws-private-link

I have an endpoint service in ACCOUNT1 and endpoint in ACCOUNT2. Can i disassociate the load balancer NLB1 from endpoint service and associate another load balancer NLB2, in order to migrate the users to another service(NLB2) ?

I am getting an error saying:

`The following Network Load Balancers still have existing VPC Endpoint connections and cannot be removed`

It seems, i cant migrate users to another service just by replacing the load balancer. I have to replace target groups of the load banacer to do this?